# Login into Website using MSXML2.XMLHTTP

Tags: excel, web-scraping, msxml, vba

I am able to log into a website using the following code

```
Sub OpenWmtVO()
On Error GoTo RunWebObjError

Dim ErrorCounter As Integer

SetUpObject

Restart:

'Disable pop-up messages
objIExplorer.Silent = True   
objIExplorer.Visible = True 'for testing change to true    
'open page
objIExplorer.Navigate "https://wmtscheduler.faa.gov/WMT_Login/"

'wait till page is fully opened
Do While objIExplorer.Busy Or Not objIExplorer.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

 'set user ID and password in textboxes
objIExplorer.Document.getElementById("hprLogin_chkViewOnly").Click
objIExplorer.Document.getElementById("hprLogin_adUserName").Value = CurUsr
objIExplorer.Document.getElementById("hprLogin_adPass").Value = CurPw

objIExplorer.Document.all.Item("hprLogin$btnSubmit").Click
    Do While objIExplorer.Busy Or Not objIExplorer.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

I would like to use MSXML2.XMLHTTP as it is much faster and once logged in I can irritate through between 29 and 42 pages for the data I need much quicker. However I am not sure how to do the initial logging into this site with MSXML2.XMLHTTP Any ideas or help would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found how to have windows pass credentials automatically, but you can hard code them like xmlhttp.Open("POST",url,false, "username", "password")